# Join table on Count

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in Access, one containing IDs (not unique) and some Name and one containing IDs (not unique) and Location. I would like to return a third table that contains only the IDs of the elements that appear more than 1 time in either Names or Location.

Table 1

```
ID    Name
1     Max
1     Bob
2     Jack
```

Table 2

```
ID   Location
1    A
2    B
```

Basically in this setup it should return only ID 1 because 1 appears twice in Table 1 :

```
ID 
1
```

I have tried to do a JOIN on the tables and then apply a COUNT but nothing came out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that I think will work in MS Access:

```
(select id
 from table1
 group by id
 having count(*) > 1
) union  -- note:  NOT union all
(select id
 from table2
 group by id
 having count(*) > 1
);
```

MS Access does not allow `union`/`union all` in the `from` clause.  Nor does it support `full outer join`.  Note that the `union` will remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Group By and Having clause should help you

```
select ID    
From Table1
Group by ID    
having count(1)>1
union
select ID    
From Table2
Group by ID    
having count(1)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you do not need to join tables to find duplicate records, if your table is what you gave above, simply use:

`With A
as
(
select ID,count(*) as Times From table group by ID
)
select * From A where A.Times>1`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand what query you already tried, but this should work:

```
select table1.ID
  from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
 group by table1.ID
having count(*) > 1
```

Or if you have ID's in one table but not the other

```
select table1.ID
  from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
 group by table1.ID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This approach assumes that all ids are in both tables.

Comment: The assumption is reasonable given the info in the question, but ok... fixed.